# Map boolean function to cells

Tags: minimize, boolean-expression, synthesis, circuit-diagram

I need to map a known Boolean expression to AND,OR,NOT gates **optimally** (or almost optimally :D ),
i.e. do the cell-library binding of the expression (aka technology mapping).

The expression has  4 input variables (A,B,C,D) and produces 4 output functions F1, F2, F3, F4.

Is there a simple tool that can carry out the task?

**The Boolean expression:**

F1 = A' B C D' + A' B' C' D' + A' B C' D' + A B' C  + A' B C D + A B' C' D + A' B' C D

F2 = A' B' C' D' + A' B' C' D + A B C'  + A' B C D + B' C D' + A B' C' D

F3 = A' B C D' + A B D + B' C D' + A B' C' D + A' B' C D + A B' D'

F4 = A B C' D + A' B C' D' + A' B' C' D + A C D' + A' B C D + A' B' C D + A B' D'

Answer (score 1):

Using `Logic Friday 1` with the following input:

```
Entered:
F1 = A' B C D' + A' B' C' D' + A' B C' D' + A B' C + A' B C D + A B' C' D + A' B' C D;
F2 = A' B' C' D' + A' B' C' D + A B C' + A' B C D + B' C D' + A B' C' D;
F3 = A' B C D' + A B D + B' C D' + A B' C' D + A' B' C D + A B' D';
F4 = A B C' D + A' B C' D' + A' B' C' D + A C D' + A' B C D + A' B' C D + A B' D';
```

The "exact minimize" operation produced:

```
Minimized:
F1 = A B' C  + A B' D + A' C' D' + A' B C  + A' C D;
F2 = A B C'  + B' C D' + A' B C D + A' B' C'  + B' C' D;
F3 = A' B' C  + A B D + A' C D' + A B' C'  + A B' D';
F4 = A' B' D + A' C D + A B' D' + A C D' + A B C' D + A' B C' D';
```

Next operation is "map to gates" (gates selected from a list):

[image]